# GLX problem, many programs not running

Tags: debian, x11, gpu, radeon

Many of my programs are not running, with this error:

```
get chip id failed: -1 [13]
param: 4, val: 0
[intel_init_bufmgr:1189] Error initializing buffer manager.
Segmentation fault
```

When I try running `glxinfo` this is what I get:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

I have two GPU's one Integrated intel, and another AMD Radeon 6490hd with open source radeon drivers on Debian testing.

I can't even log on into KDE and Gnome, but I can log on into i3, lxde and dwm.

Update:
Here is my Xorg.0.log:
http://pastebin.com/gJkFLAh7

Update 2:
It seems I was unable to update any of the xserver-xorg-video-* packages because they wanted the xorg-abi-20, even though I already had xorg-abi-23
NOw I updated those manually with gdebi.
sudo update-glx --config-glx gives me:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative glx (providing /usr/lib/glx).

  Selection    Path                    Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/nvidia          100       auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/mesa-diverted   5         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/nvidia          100       manual mode
```

NOte, I have an integrated Intel and Radeon HD6490. I have two monitors. But I get the same issues with using only one.

Comment: Your accelerated 3D (OpenGL) doesn't work. Please put the output of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` in a pastebin, and add a link.

Comment: Here, I added the pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the log shows, you have installed the GLX module for **NVIDIA** cards,

```
(II) LoadModule: "glx"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
(II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
     compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
     Module class: X.Org Server Extension
(II) NVIDIA GLX Module  375.26  Thu Dec  8 17:59:51 PST 2016
```

which only works for NVIDIA cards and nothing else. OTOH, both the modesetting driver for the Intel card and the radeon driver get initialized. One Monitor is connected to the HDMI output of the Intel card, the Radeon driver only has a VGA output, but doesn't get EDID information for it, so I'm not sure if anything is connected to that.

Install the correct GLX packages (AFAIK, `libgl1-mesa-*` for all Intel cards, at least that's what I use for my Intel card, and for the Radeon card as well), and verify in the log that they work.

If your second monitor is actually connected to the Intel card and not the Radeon, you might consider disabling the Radeon card.

Comment: Actually Debian for some reason likes to install nvidia stuff on my system. IDK why though. Thx. I will try your fix tomorrow.

Comment: I updated the question. I had those packages already installed.

Comment: So select `mesa-diverted` manually, restart X server or reboot, and check if the correct GLX is used. Alternatively, remove the nvidia packages (you won't need them anyway), and let the "auto" mode select the mesa ones.

Comment: I did and it worked. It also seems it is using my radeon still for stuff like games.